# Eclipse disliked @Override annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, overriding

After I have created my project from scratch, played with maven dependency control and copied all my old files to a new project, I found that Eclipse now sweared on @Override annotations. It says that "method must override superclass method" when this annotation present and stays cool if not. Also it does not autoinsert this annotation when using quick input.

Why this can be?

Comment: Does your method, in fact, override a parent class?  What java version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Change your maven pom to enforce Java 6 or 7. I've had this problem before where if you import a project with a pom, it defaults to Java 1.5 JDK.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely (want to) put `@Override` on a method inherited from an interface. This is only valid since Java 1.6, your Eclipse project is most likely set to source level 1.5 (alternatively you're running a very outdated 1.5 JDK, but that's unlikely)

Comment: @Matt Overriding on interfaces really only does work on Java6+ - an extremely annoying limitation everybody stumbles upon sooner than later. Overriding exists since 1.5 but only when overriding methods of classes. Or am I misunderstanding your post?